# no server log in directory:logs; deployment error in netbeans:Starting of server GlassFish timed out

Tags: deployment, netbeans, glassfish

I downloaded glassfish 3.1.2 with Netbeans 7.1.2. Glassfish worked many times. But now it does'nt want to start.
Here is what I have in netbeans:

Starting GlassFish Server 3.1.2
Starting GlassFish Server 3.1.2
C:\Users\أبو داود\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HelloWeb\nbproject\build-impl.xml:721: Deployment error: Starting of server GlassFish Server 3.1.2 has timed-out
See the server log for details.
BUILD FAILED (total time: 20 minutes 0 seconds)

I noticed that logs wich is in domain1 does'nt contain any file.
I tried to start the server from the cmd, i did the following:
cd C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2\glassfish\bin
C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2\glassfish\bin>asadmin start-domain domain1

Here is what i received:

```
java.io.IOException: Couldn't get lock for C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2\glas
sfish\domains\domain1\logs\server.log
        at java.util.logging.FileHandler.openFiles(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.logging.FileHandler.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncherLogger.addLogFileHandler(
GFLauncherLogger.java:100)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.launcher.GFLauncher.setup(GFLauncher.java:18
9)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.StartDomainCommand.createLauncher(StartD
omainCommand.java:209)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.StartDomainCommand.executeCommand(StartD
omainCommand.java:107)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CLICommand.execute(CLICommand.java:264)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain.executeCommand(AsadminMain.j
ava:306)
        at com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AsadminMain.main(AsadminMain.java:238)
Attente du dلmarrage de domain1 ..Erreur lors du dلmarrage de domain domain1.
Le serveur a quittل le processus prلmaturلment avec le code de sortie 1.
Avant son arrمt, il a gلnلrل la sortie suivante :

Launching GlassFish on Felix platform
ERROR: Unable to create cache directory: C:\Program Files\glassfish-3.1.2\glassf
ish\domains\domain1\osgi-cache\felix
ERROR: Error creating bundle cache. (java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to creat
e cache directory.)
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create cache directory.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.<init>(BundleCache.java:
131)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:629)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.r
un(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:88)
Exception in thread "Thread-1" java.lang.RuntimeException: org.osgi.framework.Bu
ndleException: Error creating bundle cache.
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.r
un(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:90)
Caused by: org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Error creating bundle cache.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:634)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiFrameworkLauncher$1.r
un(OSGiFrameworkLauncher.java:88)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to create cache directory.
        at org.apache.felix.framework.cache.BundleCache.<init>(BundleCache.java:
131)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.init(Felix.java:629)
        ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain.main(GlassFishMa
in.java:97)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain.main(ASMain.java:55)
Caused by: org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishException: java.lang.NullPointerExc
eption
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:164)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime._bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime
.java:157)
        at org.glassfish.embeddable.GlassFishRuntime.bootstrap(GlassFishRuntime.
java:110)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher.launch(
GlassFishMain.java:112)
        ... 6 more
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.newFramework(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:230)
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuild
er.build(OSGiGlassFishRuntimeBuilder.java:133)
        ... 9 more
Error stopping framework: java.lang.NullPointerException
java.lang.NullPointerException
        at com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.GlassFishMain$Launcher$1.run(G
lassFishMain.java:203)
```

What should I do to run glassfish on netbeans. thank you in advance

Comment: Do you have the server.log file open in an editor somewhere?

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same problem with Glassfish 3.1.2 and Netbeans 7.2beta on a Windows 7 platform.

I have changed the **Users** permissions to **Full control** in the Security tab of the properties setting for the glassfish installation directory and subdirectories.

I also changed the **Compatibilty "Run this program as an administrator"** setting for my Netbeans installation, as suggested by Netbeans when it encountered an error with glassfish.

I don't fully (or at all) understand the security in Windows 7 so am unsure what other implications this might have on my system. It seems to be that even when you are the administrator Windows treats you as a user unless you specifically tell it to do otherwise.